# Python scraping; multiple functions to work together as a whole

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession

# Function to scrape all of product titles from the page
def getTitle(url):
    session = HTMLSession()
    r = session.get(url)
    r.html.render(sleep=1)
    
    products = []
    for item in r.html.xpath('//*[@class="a-size-medium a-color-base a-text-normal"]'):
        product = item.text
        products.append(product)
    return products
```

```
# Function to run the getTitle function by product names instead of URL
def get_url(search_text):
    template = 'https://www.amazon.com/s?k={}'
    search_term = search_text.replace(' ', '+')
    
    url = template.format(search_term)
    url += '&pages={}'
    url_list = []

# Trying to get a list of URLs for from page1 to 20
    for x in range(1,21):
        next_url = url.replace('{}', str(x))
        url_list.append(next_url)

    return url_list
```

```
# A list of URLs in the form of https://www.amazon.com/s?k=amazon+echo&page=# 
test = get_url('amazon echo')
more_tests = getTitle(test)
```

```
# Iterate thru the list of URLs from the code above and collect those that have the word "Echo" on the product titles

filtered_test = []
for uli in more_tests:
    if "echo" in uli.lower():
        print({uli})
        filtered_test.append(uli)
    else:
        print("skip")
```

I can generate a list of URLs from product page#1 to 20.

And I just want to scrape product titles from each number of page.

But when I run the code above, I only get the URLs, not the ultimate result of product titles..

Wondering if I need to make a separate function for *going through each page* part.
Looks like I am making this over-complicated.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: is it hitting your `else` condition?

Comment: I think the whole codes hit ```else``` condition once before I made some changes on the code I wrote above. But now with those, it only generates URLs, instead of Product Titles.